# iPhone app horizontal scrolling bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to implement a horizontal scrolling bar with numerical values similar to the tip bar in te LevelUp app. Any tip or advise would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Take view at bottom of you viewcontroller. Add UIScrollview on it. Set content size to scroll view where width of scroll view should be more than the current one. 
  For numeric values you can use button and set its label as numeric, because of this you can set action to them. If you want to put limited numeric values in the form of button then you can set button statically on view. Or if you want to set large numeric values then you have create button dynamically and add it to view.